# How to focus a paper-input with Polymer 1.9.1?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I need to focus paper input in a paper dialog box. I have tried all available solution but nothing is working.

```
this.$.homeSearch.$.input.focus();
```

this is my markaup

```
<paper-input  id="homeSearch" class="home-search-btn" placeholder="Where do you want to go?" no-label-float value="{{searchText}}">

</paper-input>
```

I don't want autofocus when page load. I need to fire focus event from a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
this.$.homeSearch.$.input.focus();
```

, you can do

```
this.$.homeSearch.focus();
```

instead. `paper-input` inherits from `HTMLElement` by default so it already has a `focus` method built-in.

Comment: This solution works on paper input but I used the paper input in a paper-dialog. I want to focus the input when dialog is open. I have a method openDialog: function() {this.$.animated.open(); this.$.homeSearch.focus();} but it doesn't focus.

Comment: @aaron it doesn't focus because of render time propably. Just to test it, set for example 2 seconds timeout before calling  `this.$.homeSearch.focus()`. if it works, then you can try paper-dialog event `iron-overlay-opened` or `Polymer.renderStatus.afterNextRender`. i haven't tested it.